# PySimpleGUI Output element linebreak

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pysimplegui

i am using PySimpleGUI as a tkinter wrapper and it works like a charm, but:

When i am printing something to the output element it performs a linebreak
whenever the given character limit per line is reached.

Can i somehow change it to break line when it can't display the current word
fully with the remaining line length?

Cheers

EDIT for sample image:

[image: Error_Sample]

Comment: Please include some code to understand it better

Comment: Don't know what code would clarify so i added a picture.

Comment: What would qualify would be something runnable that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I've never used pysimplegui, but the tkinter text widget supports word wrapping. Do you have the ability to directly configure the text widget?

Comment: @BryanOakley the Output Element doesn't seem to have this property.

Comment: Yes, but you've tagged this with `tkinter` so I'm assuming that tkinter is used as the backend. The question I asked was whether you can get a reference to the underlying tkinter widget.

Comment: @BryanOakley PySimpleGUI wraps the tkinter module that is why i tagged it. Sadly i have no further experience in GUI programming, since i usually work in data science and ML only so i can't really answer your question.

Comment: The `Output` element has a property `TKOut` which is `TKOutput` element.  And the attribute `output` of `TKOutput` element is actually tkinter `Text` object.

Comment: Using the Multiline Element would work best for this as it's already setup to wrap at the "word" level.  You can now re-route stdout to a multiline element as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Output` element has a property `TKOut` which is `TKOutput` element. And the attribute `output` of `TKOutput` element is actually tkinter `Text` object which you can use to configure the wrapping mode.

Below is an simple example:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Text('GameFinder', font=('Helvetica', 24, 'bold'))],
    [sg.In(key='-IN-', size=(40,1)), sg.Button('Search')],
    [sg.Output(key='-OUT-', size=(80, 20))],
]

window = sg.Window('Game Finder', layout, element_justification='center').finalize()
window['-OUT-'].TKOut.output.config(wrap='word') # set Output element word wrapping

print('''
i am using PySimpleGUI as a tkinter wrapper and it works like a charm, but:

When i am printing something to the output element it performs a linebreak whenever the given character limit per line is reached.

Can i somehow change it to break line when it can't display the current word fully with the remaining line length?

Cheers
''')

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

---

And the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that does it. In one answer you leveled up my understanding of GUIs tenfold! Cheers mate.